# How to get out of Graveyard?

Tags: hyperrogue

Happens both in the web demo and in the downloadable free version; didn't purchase full version yet, so not sure if the mechanics haven't been changed.

[The official guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=390176864) doesn't list Graveyard as a trap zone. Yet I can't seem to get out of there. Recently in the downloadable version I used Orb of Safety in the Graveyard that was right next to the Great Walls; No matter how long I try to walk in a random direction I cant seem to be able to reach any other zone.

Or do I have to complete Haunted Woods in order to be allowed out of Graveyard?

Answer (score 2):

Great Walls seem significantly less frequent in the Graveyard than usual (apparently, once Haunted Woods start being generated, it is hard to find a straight line which does not cross their border, and thus the game cannot generate a Great Wall), but other than that, there is nothing special about escaping the Graveyard. I have confirmed that it is possible to escape in the web version.